# How to format JSON in Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, json, json-ld

For the following Google `JSON-LD` structure ...

```
<script type="application/ld+json" id="datablock-1">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "honorificPrefix": "Dr",
  "givenName": "Albert",
  "familyName": "Einstein",
  "honorificSuffix": "PhD",
  "jobTitle": "Professor of Physics",
  "worksFor": [ {
      "@type": "EducationalOrganization",
      "department": "School of Science",
      "parentOrganization": "Princeton University",
      "address": [ {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "One Relativity Way",
          "addressCountry": "USA" } ]
    } ]
}
</script>
```

this `HTML` + `JavaScript` works:

```
<body>
    <dl><dt>Big Ideas</dt><dd id="dd-1"></dd></dl>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var data = $("#datablock-1").html();
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var people = json["worksFor"];
    for (i=0; i<=people.length; i++) {
        var a=json["givenName"];
        var b=json["familyName"];
        var c=json["honorificSuffix"];
        var d=json["worksFor"][i]["parentOrganization"];
        $('#dd-1').append("<dd>"+a+" "+b+", "+c+". "+" "+d+"."+" "+"</dd>");
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Now I need to reach one level deeper in the object and add information about `"@type": "PostalAddress"`.

But this `HTML` + `JavaScript` does not work:

```
<body>
    <dl><dt>Big Ideas</dt><dd id="dd-1"></dd></dl>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var data = $("#datablock-1").html();
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var people = json["worksFor"]["address"];
    for (i=0; i<=people.length; i++) {
        var a=json["givenName"];
        var b=json["familyName"];
        var c=json["honorificSuffix"];
        var d=json["worksFor"][i]["parentOrganization"];
        var e=json["worksFor"]["address"][i]["streetAddress"];
        $('#dd-1').append("<dd>"+a+" "+b+", "+c+". "+" "+d+"."+" "+e+"</dd>");
    }
</script>
</body>
```

**What am I doing wrong? How to correct the error?**

Comment: Which @type object and what value?

Comment: @AdamJeffers `"@type": "PostalAddress"` and key `"address"` and value `"streetAddress"`

Comment: You are trying to access "address" from "worksFor". You need another loop on "worksfor" since its an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you just hop into postal address from the top, without changing the condition? I've changed your `people` variable name to `worksFor` since that is what you are iterating through, since it doesn't look like you have a list of people atm. Maybe I'm wrong?

```
<body>
    <dl><dt>Big Ideas</dt><dd id="dd-1"></dd></dl>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var data = $("#datablock-1").html();
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var worksFor= json["worksFor"];
    for (i=0; i<=worksFor.length; i++) {
        var a=json["givenName"];
        var b=json["familyName"];
        var c=json["honorificSuffix"];
        var d=json["worksFor"][i]["parentOrganization"];
        var e=json["worksFor"][i]["address"][0]["streetAddress"];//this line is changed
        $('#dd-1').append("<dd>"+a+" "+b+", "+c+". "+" "+d+"."+e+"</dd>");
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Does your solution work for you? It's not working on my end.

Comment: I missed that address is an array, that might work now.

Comment: OK, got it working, but please update your answer as follows. Change `postalAddress` to `streetAddress` and modify the `append` to `"+d+"."+e+"</dd>"`

Comment: Also, please explain why you changed `people` to `worksFor`. Reason is that I have other classes to add at the same level as `worksFor` in the JSON-LD structure. Examples are `alumniOf` and `sameAs`. I used `people` as the parent for those keys.

Comment: So I could modify your code easier, if people is the correct name, by all means flip it back.

Comment: TY. The important lesson for me here is the use of [0] as the separator. I did not know to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This line fails:

```
people = json["worksFor"]["address"]
```

And you end up `people` as `undefined`, reason being `json["worksFor"]` gives you array.

Comment: Would you show me the proper way to compose this? I'll accept the working answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me fine...

```
var json  = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "honorificPrefix": "Dr",
  "givenName": "Albert",
  "familyName": "Einstein",
  "honorificSuffix": "PhD",
  "jobTitle": "Professor of Physics",
  "worksFor": [ {
      "@type": "EducationalOrganization",
      "department": "School of Science",
      "parentOrganization": "Princeton University",
      "address": [ {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "One Relativity Way",
          "addressCountry": "USA" } ]
    } ]
}


json = JSON.parse(json);

json.worksFor[0].address[0]["@type"].PostalAddress.address = 'streetAddress'
```

Comment: Correctomundo. But the issue is that the solution has to work with a Google JSON-LD structure. The JSON-LD is a separate structure that is then formatted by JavaScript processing. To say it another way, your solution is not valid on Google Structured Data Testing Tool.